# Does the unix calendar program `pal` support line breaks?

Tags: command-line

The unix program `pal` is one of a variety of command-line calendar programs.

Based on the `man` page, each line refers to an event, and it does not mention event descriptions that span multiple lines at all.

I am trying to insert a multiline event description, and tried with `Line1\nLine2`, as well as `Line1\rLine2`, both of which were printed literally by `pal`.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get multi-line event descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.  I dug through the source code and you **can** force a line break (CTRL+V,CTRL+M), but this actually messes up the display.  The event stays on the same line but the line break starts over at the beginning and overwrites the characters.

Given the following two examples:

`00000325 Popeye statue unveiled, Crystal City TX Spinach Festival, 1937`

outputs

`Wed 26 Mar 2014 - Tomorrow
* History: Popeye statue unveiled, Crystal City TX Spinach Festival, 1937`

while

`00000326 Popeye statue unveiled, Crystal City ^MTX Spinach Festival, 1937`

outputs

`Wed 26 Mar 2014 - Tomorrow
TX Spinach Festival, 1937unveiled, Crystal City`